# iOS 8.4 : UITextField clear is not on left for RTL (right to left) Language (Hebrew)

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextfield, right-to-left, hebrew

On iOS 8.4 the clear button of UITextField is not on Left for RTL Language (Hebrew). Same code works fine on 9.X.

Is there a spesific thing that I need to do for 8.4

[image]